# Firestore != query error: Argument of type '"!="' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with my typescript compiler that i get error for this query :

```
const xxx = admin.firestore().collection('xxx')
.where('end', '!=', timestampDate).where('end', '<', timestampDate).get();
```

> error : Argument of type '"!="' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'.ts(2345).

any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your Firebase/Firestore libraries to the latest version.  Not-equals queries were not available until very recently.  According to the @google-cloud/firestore release notes, you need to be on version [4.3.0 or later](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v4.3.0).  If you're using the Firebase Admin SDK to get access to the same library, try the latest 9.3.0.

Comment: more specifically ```npm i @google-cloud/firestore firebase-admin@latest```