# How can I make this Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm a Firestore newbie and I need to make a query. I have this database structure:

```
{
  "businesses": {
    "1" : {
      "name": "bla",
      "employees": {
        "1" : {
          "name": "Juan",
          "schedules": {
            "1": {
              "scheduleId" : "72",
              "from": "21/08/2020"
            }
          }
        },
        "schedules": {
          "72": {
            //some properties
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given a `businessId` and a `scheduleId`, I need to fetch all the business' employees having that `scheduleId` assigned.

I have tried this:

```
export async function getEmployeesWithSchedule(businessId: string, scheduleId: string): Promise<Employee[]> {
    const docs = (await admin.firestore().collection(`businesses/${businessId}/employees`)
         .where("schedules.scheduleId", "==", scheduleId)
         .get()).docs;
   //extract results
}
```

But I'm geting no results. How should I make this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `where` clause. You should only get back docs where the `schedules` map contains a key-value-pair with key `scheduleId` and a `non-null` value:

```
const docs = (await admin.firestore().collection(`businesses/${businessId}/employees`)
         .where(`schedules.${scheduleId}`, "!=", null)
         .get()).docs;
```

Comment: I get this error: `Argument of type '"!="' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WhereFilterOp'.`

Comment: I think you have to upgrade your firebase admin SDK to a newer version for the `!=` operator to be recognized. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64595002/firestore-query-error-argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter for more details